# on click display the div of attachments

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div like below in my html which by default has display none.

```
<div class="attach-div" style ="display:none;">
    <button><i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

Now I have a form like below

```
<div class="form-comment">
 <form action="">
  <div class="con">
     <button><i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Your Response">
     <button class=""><i class="fa fa-paperclip attach-detail" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
   </div>
     <input type="button" class="submit" value="ADD">
  </form>
 </div>
```

On the click of the paperclip icon, I wish to show the class.

Here's what I am trying using the jquery.

```
$(".attach-detail").click(function() {
  $(".attach-div").css('display', 'block');
});
```

Below is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mssecwL2/).

Comment: What is `$(".popup-wrapper")` pointing to? I can't see that class in your code.

Comment: Default button type is `submit`. So anyway in your code, clicking the button will submit the `form`. So firstly set its type to `button`: `<button type="button" class=""><i class="fa fa-paperclip attach-detail" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`

Comment: Seems It is still submitting it even though I have it like below..

`<button type = "button" class=""><i class="fa fa-paperclip attach-detail" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket on the end of your JavaScript - you also need to use the attach-div class in your fiddle.

```
$(".attach-detail").click(function() {
  $(".attach-div").css('display', 'block');
});
```

You may also want to prevent the default submit behaviour (causes a postback)

Do this by preventing the default action or returning false:

```
$(".attach-detail").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".attach-div").css('display', 'block');
    return false;
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mssecwL2/1/)

Comment: Well, I forgot the put it here, although I have It closed in my js file..

Comment: Does this answer do what you need @Suraj?

Comment: Why preventDefault *and* `return: false`?

Comment: It somehow seems to work here in the fiddle, I now know what I was missing but I think need to check why It isn't helping. Probably need to remove the button type..

Comment: On the click, It is simply reloading everything.